# Including a header file into a header file without exposing it's content to the includer

Tags: c++, header, wrapper

I would like to write a c++ wrapper for a C API. for this it is most convenient to just include the C-API header in my own header, but this also includes the header into the file of the outer system, that should not be exposed to the C-API.

capi.h

```
enum MyFlags {
    MY_FLAG_A,
    MY_FLAG_B,
};

void FOO_bar(int flags);
```

cppapi.hh

```
#include "capi.h"

enum class MyFlags { 
    A = MY_FLAG_A, 
    B = MY_FLAG_B 
};

namespace foo {
    void bar(MyFlags flags) { 
        FOO_bar((int)flags); 
    }
}
```

it is just to translate c naming convention into c++ language features. So when using the C++ variant of the language, I would like that the c_api is not available to my auto completion and therefore not accidently used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a namespace `detail` in your projects namespace, and include the C header there.

If the C header does not define en `extern "C"`- block when included from C++, do one of these:

- Wrap with an external `extern "C"` block and verify the C header is, if included thus, valid and equivalent C++. (Special attention to enum sizes and inline functions).
- Make it valid and equivalent C++ using `#ifdef __cplusplus`.

Thus, all those C functions are hidden in the internal implementation-detail namespace, and won't bother anyone.

```
namespace foo {
    namespace internal {
        extern "C" {
            #include "capi.h"
        }
    }
    // Function alias
    using bar = internal::FOO_bar;
    // Type alias
    using config_t = internal::FOO_config;
}
```

Selectively get those symbols you need into the `FOO`-namespace using `using`.

BTW: Your forwarder-function should really be `inline`!

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the linker won't choke on this?

Comment: The linker won't choke, the compiler might if the header uses C++ keywords like normal identifiers.

Comment: Ok. There's even an explanation in the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685994/c-extern-c-functions-inside-a-namespace: The namespace information of the symbols defined `extern "C"` won't be visible to the linker, so this should work.

Comment: Also, use `using` for getting those names you want into your module namespace.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to arrange things using

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
/* C++ code here, including #include*/
#else
/*C code*/
#endif
```

Comment: sorry, how is this supposed to help me here? I am compiling with c++ all the time.